# Output of testing if string is Palindrome

Tags: python, recursion

Output of testing if string is Palindrome

```
def isPalindrome1(s):
    """Assume s is an str
       Returns True if s is a palindrome;False otherwise.
         Punctuation marks, blanks, and capitalization are
         ignored."""
    def toChars(s):
        s = s.lower()# Means:s = 'ABCD',if s referenced by s.lower,then s='abcd'.
        ans = ''
        for c in s:
            if c in'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
                ans =ans+c
        return ans

    def isPal(s):
        print ' isPal called with',s
        if len(s)<=1:
            print ' About to return True from base case'
            return True
        else:
            ans = s[0] == s[-1] and isPal(s[1:-1])
            print ' About to return',ans,'for',s
            return ans 

    return isPal(toChars(s)) 

def testIspalindrome1():
    print 'Try dogGod'
    print isPalindrome1('dogGod')
    print 'Try doGood'
    print isPalindrome1('doGood')
```

Execute the function "testIspalindrome1()" will get the following result:

```
Try dogGod
 isPal called with doggod
 isPal called with oggo
 isPal called with gg
 isPal called with 
 **About to return True from base case
 About to return True for gg
 About to return True for oggo
 About to return True for doggod**
True
Try doGood
 isPal called with dogood
 isPal called with ogoo
 isPal called with go
 About to return False for go
 About to return False for ogoo
 About to return False for dogood
False
```

What's the logic of execution on the section in stars?

Comment: `def isPalindrome1(s): return s[::-1]==s`

Comment: What are "bald letters"?  I don't understand the issue.

Comment: @Prune bold. Typo

Comment: This is still an unclear question to me... "what is the logic of execution" is a bit tough to answer beyond some general explanation or diagram on how recursion works.

Comment: use debugger and see the execution sequence

Answer (score 1):

Everytime the recursion is returned from, it must continue from where the method was called.

```
ans = s[0] == s[-1] and isPal(s[1:-1])  # This branches off, like any other function call 
print ' About to return',ans,'for',s  # This waits for recursion to finish
```

Comment: "About to return True for gg" I don't understand how the recursion get to this result.

Comment: especially for " s = 'gg' "

Comment: Write it down on paper, then. Do you understand what `s[1:-1]` is doing?

Comment: `print ' isPal called with',s`... Then it recurses, then it must print `s` again at `print ' About to return',ans,'for',s`, so if you don't understand that, then you also don't understand `isPal called with gg`?

Answer (score 0):

Logic:

- Reduce the original input to only lower-case letters
- Are the end letters the same?  If not, this is not a palindrome.
- If they match, then this is a potential palindrome.
- Strip off the end letters; recur on the remaining string.
- If you run out of letters to match, it's a palindrome: all of the ends got matched up.

Does that explain the logic for you?

**COMING BACK FROM THE BASE CASE**

`About to return True for gg` comes from this code:

```
ans = s[0] == s[-1] and isPal(s[1:-1])
print ' About to return',ans,'for',s
```

Let's look at the expression in the assignment, replacing symbols with their values:

```
ans = "g" == "g" and True
```

We get the final `True` from the final recursive call, where the argument is the empty string.  The base case returns `True`, which we use here.
The end letters match, and the middle letters (the null string) form a palindrome, so the full string is also a palindrome.  Therefore, we return `True` to the previous call.

This call now goes through the same process with the string `oggo`:

```
and = "o" == "o" and True
```

... and so on, until we reach the original call.

Comment: "About to return True for gg" I don't understand how the recursion get to this result.

Answer (score 0):

```
 **About to return True from base case
 About to return True for gg
 About to return True for oggo
 About to return True for doggod**
```

This keeps on removing a character from front and from back .
and keeps on checking pallindrome